# Reflect.getMetadata() returns undefined although metadata is set

Tags: typescript, annotations, metadata, reflect, decoration

I'm trying to use annotations in my TypeScript application. However I must be doing something wrong, as `Reflect.getMetadata()` always returns `undefined`, although I can see in the debugger that the metadata seems to be set correctly.

my-class.ts with an annotated property:

```
import { jsonIgnore } from './json-ignor';

export class MyClass {
    public prop1: string;
    @jsonIgnore() public prop2: string;
}
```

json-ignore.ts with the decoration and annotation function:

```
const JSON_IGNORE = 'jsonIgnore';

export function jsonIgnore(): any {
    return Reflect.metadata(JSON_IGNORE, true);
}

export function jsonIgnoreReplacer(key: string, value: any): any {
    const meta = Reflect.getMetadata(metadataKey, object, propertyKey);
    // do something with the metadata...
}
```

Now `meta` is always `undefined`. But when I check the `MyClass` instance in the debugger, I see that it has the metadata set in its prototype:

- myClass: MyClass

  - prop1: 'foo'
  - prop2: 'bar'
  - [[Prototype]]: Object

    - __metadata__:

      - prop2:

        - jsonIgnore: true

I can also access the `__metadata__` and it's entries easily (`Object.getPrototypeOf(myClass).__metadata__.prop2.jsonIgnore`), but that's definitely a hack when there is an API for it and will most likely not work in different browsers?

So if anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong... that would be very much appreciated!

More info:
tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have defined your metadatakey as a string.
Following the instructions in the TypeScript docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators), you need to define the key as a Symbol. I've also noticed that the Symbol actually needs to be the same instance in the decorator and the function that uses the metadata. Try this:

```
    const jsonIgnoreMetadataKey = Symbol("jsonIgnore");
    export function jsonIgnore(): any {
        return Reflect.metadata(jsonIgnoreMetadataKey , true);
    }

    export function jsonIgnoreReplacer(key: string, value: any): any {
        const meta = Reflect.getMetadata(jsonIgnoreMetadataKey , object, propertyKey);
        // do something with the metadata...
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I totally missed the "Symbol" part!

Comment: Hi @Will I'm glad it helped, if this is a solution please consider marking it as the accepted answer.